# WPF performance problems with PresentationTraceSources

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

We're registering a trace listener to capture binding errors in our WPF application. This works great when the application is started with debugger attached, the WPF trace events are then automatically activated.

When running outside the debugger, the trace events must be manually enabled with the following line:

```
PresentationTraceSources.Refresh();
```

This works so far that we do get the binding error trace events. However, we also observe performance issues, for example when switching tabs repeatedly; the tab switch gets slower with every switch. With an attached debugger or when disabling the binding error trace events by commenting the above statement, the performance issues are gone. Funny thing is, that the tab switch itself does not produce any additional binding errors.

An analysis of the difference between the first tab switch and the tenth in a performance profiler shows that the longer time stems from multiple calls to `FrameworkElement.UpdateStyleProperty()`. I'm however not sure what that has to do with regards to binding error events.

So does anyone have an idea what the difference between **binding error trace events with attached debugger** and **binding error trace events with `PresentationTraceSources.Refresh()`** might be? Any help or thought is appreciated.

Comment: Using `PresentationTraceSources` output, either to the Output Window, or to an external file are both known to affect performance. Furthermore, setting the level to something high like `Verbose` can render an application totally unusable and should only be used for debugging or testing purposes.

Comment: @Sheridan Yes I know, we activate the trace events only in debug builds, and even there can they be turned off manually. However it seems strange to me that the performance impact of trace events is worse when running **without** debugger as compared to running with debugger attached.